Why Quickbooks API Refresh Token expires in a short period of time?
I am using QBO API to get every transactions using my NodeJS API and Make for daily pulling of transactions. But I am encountering an issue that I shouldn't be encounter. The refresh token I'm using will expire after a few days, sometimes after a day it will expire.
Here is what in the documentation says:
https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/Validity-of-Refresh-Token

Refresh Token is valid up to 100 days. I followed these steps to keep my refresh token valid but it is always expire in a few days after.

What I did is I am checking the access token if valid then if I get 401 response, I will regenerate new access token using the refresh token.
I am storing the access token and refresh token in the database for me to reuse the refresh token to regenerate new access token once expired.
Yep, the problem is just the refresh token expiration, it should be 100 days and not 1-3 days of validity.
I already followed the steps given in the help article above. I am generating new access token once it got 401 in the existing access token.


And then what i did is I am running an automation in Make (integromat) every 12 midnight to pull transactions in QBO.
I saw older post that has the same issue as mine 5 years ago but it didn't help me
Could someone help me find a solution to fix this? Thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Issue: Refresh Token is Expiring Each Day Instead of Lasting 100 Days
I faced a similar issue with QuickBooks Online (QBO) API, where the refresh token expired after just 24-26 hours, even though the documentation says it should last for 100 days.
Solution:
The key issue is that while the refresh token is valid for up to 100 days, the refresh token string itself changes every time you use it to generate an access token. After creating an access token, the API response returns a new refresh token along with the access token and its expiration time.
If you don’t update and use the new refresh token string from the API response and continue using the old refresh token, you'll encounter an invalid_grant error.
Action Steps:
Use the new refresh token: After every access token generation, update the refresh token in your system with the new value returned in the API response.
Store the new refresh token securely and use it for subsequent requests.
If you use an outdated refresh token string, it will lead to premature expiration issues, even though the token is supposed to last up to 100 days.
Reference: For further details, you can check the Intuit Developer help forum response.
